# How to apply formatting rules from PyCharm in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, formatting

As I understand, PyCharm uses his own set of formatting rules.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-code-style.html#editorconfig

Is there any faster way to apply same rules to the VSCode and PyCharm?

Solution could be either import formatting rules from PyCharm to VSCode OR apply same formatting rules in PyCharm as in VSCode (e.g. default formatter black). Is it possible?

Edit:

Let's say one developer using PyCharm and format document using those rules. Other developer uses VSCode with black. When developer 2 makes changes in the very long file, when he apply formatter, it also modifies formatting rules that was made by dev 1. Those changes is very annoying to review in PR, they triggered as changes, but have no impact on actual logic.

Edit2:
Better example:

PyCharm defaut

```
def test_002_enable_service_route_security_access_denied(
        reset_test_conf, enable_service_route, can_signal, can, tf, record_property 
):
```

Black

```
def test_002_enable_service_route_security_access_denied(
    reset_test_conf, enable_service_route, can_signal, can, tf, record_property 
):
```

P.S. Yes, I can manually change every indent and other option. But point is to have same formatting rules using different IDEs, with *ease of importing* rules

Update Nov.2023:
PyCharm uses own set of formatting rules, there's no 1-1 conversion between VSCode and PyCharm (like `.clang-format` files or similar)

Answer (score 1):

The settings in vscode are stored in the `settings.json` file. You can also select from the gears in the lower left corner:

[image]

With the example you mentioned, I can query format in the search box and then customize the formatting tool:

[image]

You can also add the following codes into the `settings.json` file:

```
"python.formatting.provider": "black",
```

[image]

**Add:**
The example you gave is that the line length exceeds the default value of black, so the line is automatically wrapped. You can add the following code to `settings.json` to modify the default value:

```
"python.formatting.blackArgs": [
    "max-line-length:120"
],
```

Comment: Thank you, but question is to use SAME formatting rules in both IDEs

Comment: @LeonidTsigrinski `e.g. default formatter black` I give the answer based on the example you put forward. Could you tell me in detail what kind of solution you want? Because vscode currently provides only these three formats, you can refer to the settings in github for more customized settings, such as [black](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-black-formatter).

Comment: @LeonidTsigrinski I added my answer and hope it can help you.

Comment: unfortunately, that was not the case. Point of the question is to find generic standard for applying formatting rules within different IDE's

Comment: This answer works well since there is no 1:1 conversion between pycharm and vscode. By setting the max-length to 120 you are able to achieve the same default formatting settings of pycharm on vscode.

Comment: @LeonidTsigrinski except if you found another way of solving this issue (I am facing the same issue), I think that the only way is to setup black to be an available formatter in Pycharm. Pycharm formatter is a proprietary smart tool developed by JetBrains and is not available for users with other IDEs. There's some documentation online to setup Black within Pycharm.